# Rotated Navigation Menu

Tags: css, html

I am trying to design a navigation menu that originates in the corner and disperses at a 45 deg angle:

[image: Concept]

Here is the code I have so far, with css. However, it uses absolute positioning. Is there an way to get these rotated elements to slide together?

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu{
  position: absolute;
  height:100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: black;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#home{
  top: 56px;
  left: -94px;
  width:400px;
  background-color: red;
}

#contact{
  top: 125px;
  left: -123px;
  width:600px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#about{
  top: 100px;
  left: 1100px;
  width:800px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#nav {
    float:left;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Chris Scalzi Portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav>
        <div id="logo"><a href="*"></a></div>
        <div class="menu" id="home"><a href="*"><p>Home</p></a></div>
        <div class="menu" id="contact"><a href="*"><p>Contact</p></a></div>
        <div class="menu" id="about"><a href="*"><p>About</p></a></div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

- Start by building the menu horizontally, with each item under one another.
- Each menu item would have `display: table` and each child link would have `display: table-cell` => that's the easiest way to center things vertically in CSS when your layout is pretty simple.
- I would use the link's padding to adjust the height of each menu item => bigger click/touch zone for the user (and you can use the link for a nice `:hover` effect). In general, I would try to **set as few fixed heights as possible**, to allow the content to grow if needed while preserving the element (and it's more maintainable).
- I would then put all the global sizing, positioning and rotation on the parent element: the `<nav>...</nav>`. Like this, you're controlling your component as a whole, with just a couple of CSS rules and only *one* `position: absolute`.
- Finally, you will need to adjust the element's `width` along with the `top` and `left` positions, depending on what angle you want, and the place you want it to take on your page (and each item's padding).

You'll find a POC below, loosely based on your code ;)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  color: black;
}

#logo a {
  padding: 60px 0 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

#logo a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#home    a { background-color: red;    }
#contact a { background-color: pink;   }
#about   a { background-color: yellow; }

nav {
  /* Pretty much everything is defined here: */
  position: absolute;
  width: 700px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -40px;
  left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Chris Scalzi Portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav>
        <div class="menu-item" id="logo"><a href="*">LOGO</a></div>
        <div class="menu-item" id="home"><a href="*">Home</a></div>
        <div class="menu-item" id="contact"><a href="*">Contact</a></div>
        <div class="menu-item" id="about"><a href="*">About</a></div>
    </nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to coding and this hint allowed me to create just the navigation menu I was looking for, I will post the end result of the code when I finish everything!